# Azure IOT & X509 Certificates

Tags: c#, azure, x509certificate, iot

I've been following the example code on the Azure IOT Developers Guid pages. I have a program which allows me to send messages to my devices from the cloud.

```
class CloudToDeviceMessagSender
    {
        private static ServiceClient _serviceClient;
        private static string _connectionString = Common.ConnectionStringsAndCerts.ConnectionHelperStrings.ConnectionString;

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Send Cloud-to-Device message\n");
            _serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_connectionString, TransportType.Amqp);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter message to send:");
            var message = Console.ReadLine();
            SendCloudToDeviceMessageAsync(message).Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task SendCloudToDeviceMessageAsync(string message)
        {
            var commandMessage = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));
            await _serviceClient.SendAsync("myDeviceId", commandMessage);
        }
    }
```

When I register a device I register it with an X509 certificate.

This seems to work fine as:

[image: x509 certs work]

My device reads the message it gets sent from the CloudToDeviceMessagSender.

```
public static async void ReceiveCloudToDeviceAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nReceiving cloud to device messages from service");
            while (true)
            {
                var receivedMessage = await _deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
                if (receivedMessage == null) continue;

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes()));
                Console.ResetColor();

                await _deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
            }
        }
```

My question is, how do I make it only accept messages that were sent with a valid x509 certificate that it was registered with?

A further question, if I'm to use x509 certificates to secure communication between devices and cloud, do I need 1 certificate per device or is it 1 cert that all devices use?

Comment: On your first question, dunno. Have you tried to add a device with a valid cert, revoking the cert, and checking if the device still recives messages? On your second question, it depends on how you want to manage the devices/certs. One single cert for the whole app vs. one cert for customer using your app (in case it will be paid)